# Hide table completely when image isn't populated - html for email

Tags: email

I am trying to create a table where the height will completely collapse when an image isn't populated. I am having trouble in that the table will not fully collapse when the image isn't served (through DART) - it will be blank but will be several pixels tall and the desired effect is that the height will completely collapse. Any ideas on how I can achieve this desired effect? And styling of imgs isn't the issue. Thank you!

Example:

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="435">
<tbody>
    <tr>
      <td valign="middle"><a href="$clickthrough(adv_imglink_new,concat(URL=http://ad.doubleclick.net/N536/jump/bc3.email/dailydigest;dd=,todayformat(0,MM),_,todayformat(0,dd),_,todayformat(0,yyyy),;tile=4;sz=435x103;dcove=r;us=,lookup(ADSTAGE),;us=$lookup(AD_STAGE_WEEK)$;ord=,lookup(BD_LOGINCODE),todayformat(0,yyyyMMddhhmm),?))$" target="_blank">
<img src="http://ad.doubleclick.net/N536/ad/bc3.email/dailydigest;dd=$todayformat(0,MM)$_$todayformat(0,dd)$_$todayformat(0,yyyy)$;tile=4;sz=435x103;dcove=r;us=$lookup(ADSTAGE)$;us=$lookup(AD_STAGE_WEEK)$;ord=$lookup(BD_LOGINCODE)$$todayformat(0,yyyyMMddhhmm)$?" border="0" alt=""  />
</a></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: You should inspect this in Chrome DevTools and verify what setting causes this. Right-click the element in the browser and choose inspect element. Scroll down the `Styles` tag to the bottom and investigate the dimensions. You can edit the values in this view. When you found the culprit add the CSS setting that fixes it to your CSS file or add more details about the problem to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Outlook in particular has a minimum table height of around 19px. Try using this:

`<td height="1" style="font-size: 1px; line-height: 1px;">`

Personally, I'd just design it to borrow 20px of padding from whatever you have above, and avoid line-height hack all together. If you have text above it for example, just remove the bottom padding there and add it to top pad this cell, avoiding the min-height issue all together.

Comment: I am pretty sure the line-height hack worked! I will confirm after testing ;). Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Please try to add below code

<td height="1" style="font-size: 1px; line-height: 1px; mso-line-height-rule:exactly;">

Comment: It "may"? ;) Can you not check it to make sure? Maybe this is more of a comment than an answer, really?

Answer (score -1):

Add below code <td style="font-size: 0%; line-height: 1px; mso-line-height-rule: exactly;">, then email will not have more white spacing. Its best practice to have this for out table when we create template based html email. Thanks